# Bug with logic operator "or"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic, boolean-logic

I'm learning the language python. And although it is very simple indeed, I got some unexpected results using logic operators both in IDLE and in python.

I made a simple test in IDLE like this:

```
(2 or 10) in range(1,6)
```

And my response was `True`. So far so good. However, if I do this:

```
(10 or 2) in range(1,6)
```

My response is `False`. Even though "2" is clearly inside the `range(1,6)`.

I made the same test in PyCharm and here are my responces:

```
if (2 or 10) in range(1,6):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Result: `True`

```
if (10 or 2) in range(1,6):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Result: `False`

```
if 2 or 10 in range(1,6):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Result: `True`

```
if 10 or 2 in range(1,6):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Result: `True`

I would like to know the logic behind it please.

Comment: First of all `or` in Python is **not** a logical operator. Second, it should be `10 in range(1,6) or 2 in range(1,6)`... Otherwise you have written `(10 or 2) in range(1,6))`... which resolves to `10 in range(1,6)`...

Comment: Enlight me please. Show documents for me to read, proof, evidence, something.

Comment: http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks

Comment: `or` shortcircuits. `(10 or 2)` evaluates to `10`, `(10 or 2)` evaluates to `2`. It also has higher precedence than `in`, so `if 2 or 10 in range(1,6)` is equivalent to `if 2 in range(1,6)`, while `if 10 or 2 in range(1, 6)` is equivalent to `if 10 in range(1,6)`.

Comment: I think I got it. However, how do I rewrie the code using the boolean operator "or" to check if 10 || 2 is in range?

Comment: @andseg: try using the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#any) function: `print(any(x in range(1,6) for x in [10,2]))`. There's also an `all` function that behaves like you were expecting for logical AND.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OR` returns the first `TRUE` value it encounters.

That is:

```
>>> (2 or 10) 
# returns 2
>>> (10 or 2)
# returns 10
```

**Update**

To address OP's comment below:

There are *truthy* values which evaluate to `True` and there are *falsey* values which evaluate to `False`. For example, 0 is a falsey value. Rest of the integers are truthy values. Therefore, 10 is also a truthy value.

If you do:

```
>>> if 10: # since 10 is truthy, this statement will execute.
        print("Okay!")
    else:
        print("Not okay!")

# prints "Okay!"
```

Moving on, `10 or 2 in range(1, 6)` evaluates to `10 or (2 in range(1, 6))`.

```
 10     or     (2 in range(1, 6))
\__/           \________________/
True               True

# Returns 10 because it's a truthy value. 
# OR operator only evaluates until it finds a True value.
```

Let's see another example:

```
 0      or    10
\_/          \__/
False        True

# Returns 10 because 0 is a falsey value, so the 
# OR operator continues evaluating the rest of the expression
```

Finally, let's see the `if` expression:

```
 >>> if 10 or 2 in range(1, 6):
        print("True")
     else:
        print("False")
 # prints "True"
```

It prints `True` because `10 or 2 in range(1, 6)` returns `10` and as we saw above, `if 10` evaluates to `True`, hence, the `if` block is executed.

---

**Additionally**:

The correct expression will be this:

```
>>> 10 in range(1, 6) or 2 in range(1, 6)
# returns True
```

This expression will return `True` because even though 10 is not in the given range, but 2 is.

```
10 in range(1, 6)   or   2 in range(1, 6)
\_______________/        \______________/ 
     False                     True

# Returns True because OR will keep on evaluating
# until it finds a True value
```

But if you want to check if 10 and 2 both are in the range, you'll have to use the `AND` operator:

```
>>> 10 in range(1, 6) and 2 in range(1, 6)
# returns False
```

Comment: @andseg: since you asked for a reference in a comment to your question... here's where it's documented in the [Python 3.5 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

Comment: using `(10 or 2)` returns 10.... and 10 is not in range(1,6) so it returns false. right? but what about using `10 or 2 in range(1,6)`? using idle it returns 10 as well, but in PyCharm the "if" is taken. Why?

Comment: @andseg I don't understand what you mean by *"... but in PyCharm the "if" is taken"...*. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: using IDLE, the line `10 or 2 in range(1,6)`returns 10. However, using PyCharm, the line `if 10 or 2 in range(1,6):` returns true.... which print the message "True". Why am I getting a true?

Comment: @andseg I've updated the answer and tried my best to explain. Have a look.